# Mixcloud api footer widget events?

Tags: wordpress, api, mixcloud

I've searched high and low and there's no specific instructions on how to control the mixcloud api footer widget. Does anyone know if they exist? I've seen the official developer & api pages on their website but they are very vague and just list options but not how to implement.
Thanks